# Combine vs. Cocoa Bindings

Tags: swift, macos, cocoa, combine

In general, do you feel that Combine has developed enough that it can replace Cocoa Bindings?

I want to create a data model that is totally based on Combine @Published properties and attach it to my view controller and view with Combine.

But before I spend all the effort, I wanted to get you all’s thoughts on potential pitfalls or considerations I should be taking into account. Should I just stick with tried and true Cocoa Bindings?

Thanks!

Answer (score 0):

Cocoa Bindings are great but they only work on macOS. Apple has signaled in multiple ways that the future of their frameworks is cross-platform (SwiftUI, Combine, etc). Combine is going to enter its third year soon. I'd say it's still early, but not too early.